# ISAPI_Rewrite is not working

Tags: asp-classic, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I am trying to use friendly url on my website. But it is not working.

Here is the code of my httpd.ini file

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]
   RewriteRule /([^/]+) /member.asp\?username=$1 [I,L]
```

when i try in the browser

example.com/brad

then it show this error
   HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

http://www.isapirewrite.com/ this is the website from where i get some idea about but its not working for me

Thanks
Gursharan

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this....this is for Version 3.1.0.78

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^username=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^member\.asp$ ourmembers/%1? [NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^ourmembers/([^./]+)\/$ member.asp?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: You need to specify the default document extension like index.asp, default.asp, index.html and so on. You can do this by creating a file with any of the above names and place it in the root of the site.